# What is the default anchoring style in Forest?

Tags: linguistics, forest

Drawing linguistic phrase structure trees most of the time, I use the `sn edges` from the `forest` manual as a global default, with `parent anchor=south, child anchor=north`. This outputs the following sort of trees:

[image]

However, sometimes I want to draw derivation trees, which should rather show the default anchoring of `forest`:

[image]

So I'm trying to define a `derivation tree` style that resets the global style:

```
\documentclass[
    ,crop=true
    ,varwidth=\maxdimen
    ]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
    .style={for tree={parent anchor=south,child anchor=north}},
    derivation tree/.style={
        for tree={parent anchor={},child anchor={},font=\ttfamily}}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
derivation tree
[S[NP][VP[V[\textit{eats}]][NP]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.style` is an unintended way to specify defaults, and therefore has its shortcomings. (The next version of the package will contain key `default preamble`.) It works because an empty key is called at the end of every nodes keylist ... and since it's at the end, it's impossible to override.

Workaround: redefine the empty style, as shown in the code. You can see that the redefinition is local to the environment.

```
\documentclass[
    ,crop=true
    ,varwidth=\maxdimen
    ]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  .style={for tree={parent anchor=south,child anchor=north}},
    derivation tree/.style={.style={
        for tree={parent anchor={},child anchor={},font=\ttfamily}}
      }
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
derivation tree
[S[NP][VP[V[\textit{eats}]][NP]]]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
[S[NP][VP[V[\textit{eats}]][NP]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to `default`. Wouldn't it be more intuitive to put `.style` at the beginning of the keylist?

Comment: As I said, this was an *unintended* way of specifying the default ;-)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Out of curiosity, is there a straightforward way to get the default style of `forest` for a single tree if the defaults of another library were applied in the preamble? The key `default preamble`, for example, gives you the linguistics styles if you've loaded the `linguistics` library either via `\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}` or via `\usepackage{forest} \useforestlibrary*{linguistics}`.

Comment: I believe `\forestset{default preamble=}` should do the trick, enclosed in a group, of course.